# Regex Multi Line Named Group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have an online form that customers fill out and submit that generates a purchase order. That data is also send to a monitored inbox, that I am using with power automate in business central to parse out the data, and enter it into our ERP.
An example of how I am parsing that data out:
Email Body:
**Street Address: 95 N 200 E 

City: BOUNTIFUL 

State / Province: UT 

Postal / Zip Code: 84010-4848**

The regex pattern I have been using is:

```
Street Address: (?<streetaddress>.+|)
City: (?<city>.+|)
State \/ Province: (?<state>.+|)
Postal \/ Zip Code: (?<zip>.+)
```

It works. Later in the body of the email I have:
* S12 (Amount: 730.00 USD, Special Quantity: 1546) 
* IRONWORKS DRing (Amount: 1,599.00 USD, Special Quantity: 1) 
* IRONWORKS LRing (Amount: 399.00 USD, Special Quantity: 1) 
* IRONWORKS SRing (Amount: 1,199.00 USD, Special Quantity: 1) **

My regex for this however doesn't work and I cannot understand why.

```
\* S12 \(Amount: 730.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<S12Quantity>\d+|)
\* IRONWORKS DRing \(Amount: 1,599.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<DQuantity>\d+|)
\* IRONWORKS LRing \(Amount: 399.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<LQuantity>\d+|)
\* IRONWORKS SRing \(Amount: 1,199.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<SQuantity>\d+|)
```

I'm just trying to pull the quantity for each item, but also need to later find a way to do the same thing with the revenue amount.

Comment: You must escape dots in the expression or `.` will match any character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your capture group you have an open parentheses.

```
from:
(?<S12Quantity>\d+|)

to:
(?<S12Quantity>\d+)\)
```

You'll need to account for the capture group closing `)` and the literal `)` at the end of the string.

I've tested this with the fix and it works on Rubular for me:

```
\* S12 \(Amount: 730.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<S12Quantity>\d+)\)
\* IRONWORKS DRing \(Amount: 1,599.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<DQuantity>\d+)\)
\* IRONWORKS LRing \(Amount: 399.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<LQuantity>\d+)\)
\* IRONWORKS SRing \(Amount: 1,199.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<SQuantity>\d+)\)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each line ends with `)`, and this character pattern is missing in the pattern.

Also, periods must be escaped since `.` matches any character.

Besides, `(\d+|)` is a convoluted way of saying `(\d*)` - zero or more digits.

Use

```
\* S12 \(Amount: 730\.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<S12Quantity>\d+)\)
\* IRONWORKS DRing \(Amount: 1,599\.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<DQuantity>\d*)\)
\* IRONWORKS LRing \(Amount: 399\.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<LQuantity>\d*)\)
\* IRONWORKS SRing \(Amount: 1,199\.00 USD, Special Quantity: (?<SQuantity>\d*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/i5XJyS/2)